# Search for free times in calendar with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, join

I have a users table in which I keep user info alongside their day start and end time

```
id    day_start    day_end
1     08:00:00     16:00:00
2     09:00:00     18:00:00
```

and there is another table which holds the calendar events for users

```
id    user_id    start                    end
1     1          2020-01-12 12:00:00      2020-01-12 13:30:00
2     1          2020-01-12 13:30:00      2020-01-12 14:30:00
3     1          2020-01-12 09:00:00      2020-01-12 10:30:00
```

So I am trying to filter these people based on their free time. i.e. I want to provide a start time, an end time, and an array of days of the week and find the users who are available based on these criteria.
For example, I want to say that I am looking for people who are available Saturdays or Mondays at any time between 10:00:00 to 14:00:00 and receive a list of users.

Note that a user may not be available during the whole requested time but just a fraction of the time. For example, a user who only has free time on Saturday from 11:00:00 to 11:30:00 should be listed as well.

I am looking for a MySQL query to achieve this functionality.

If the query could give the start and end time of all the free time slots would be great.
something like this

```
user_id    start                    end
1          2020-01-12 08:00:00      2020-01-12 09:00:00
1          2020-01-12 10:30:00      2020-01-12 12:00:00
1          2020-01-12 14:30:00      2020-01-12 18:00:00
2          ...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using window functions and a common-table-expression (both available in MySQL 8.0 only).

To start with, you can join both tables and use `lag()` to get the end of the *previous* event. Then, you can pull out the intervals by searching for non-adjacent rows. The first interval is indentified by the fact that it has no previous event. To get the last interval, we use `union all` and select from the cte again.

```
with cte as (
    select
        e.*,
        u.day_start,
        u.day_end,
        lag(e.dt_end) over(partition by u.id order by e.dt_start) lag_dt_end
    from events e
    inner join users u on u.id = e.user_id
)
select
    user_id,
    coalesce(lag_dt_end, concat(date(dt_start), ' ', day_start)) dt_start,
    dt_start dt_end
from cte
where 
    dt_start <> lag_dt_end 
    or (lag_dt_end is null and time(dt_start) > day_start)
union all
select 
    user_id, 
    max(dt_end), 
    concat(date(max(dt_end)), ' ', day_end)
from cte
group by user_id, day_end
having time(max(dt_end)) < day_end
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b3c361fb58722e51c11a1c8b0724af31)**:

```
user_id | dt_start            | dt_end             
------: | :------------------ | :------------------
      1 | 2020-01-12 08:00:00 | 2020-01-12 09:00:00
      1 | 2020-01-12 10:30:00 | 2020-01-12 12:00:00
      1 | 2020-01-12 14:30:00 | 2020-01-12 16:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, how is this method performance-wise? I mean does it worth it to change the DB structure for a simpler query?